# Blur/unblur action on input clearance

Tags: javascript, css

I have the situation where I want to blur and unblur a background dynamically based on the inclusion of text in an input.

The unblur happens nicely, however, the re-blur on clearance of the input is not working? Not sure if I've just been staring at this too long, but hitting up SO because I'm slowly going insane looking at this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Code below:

```html
<div>
  <form name="search" class="searchBarClass" action="/action_page.php" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="searchInput" onkeyup="unblur();blur();">
    <button type="submit"><span class="material-icons">search</span></button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="background"></div>
```

Script for update:

```js
function unblur() {
  document.getElementById("background").style.filter = "none";
}

function blur() {
  var x = document.forms["search"]["searchInput"].value;
  if (x === "") {
    document.getElementById("map").style.filter = "blur(2px)";
  }
}
```

Comment: From where is `blur()` being called? It's not in the provided HTML.

Comment: Apologies - updated above

Comment: Your `unblur()` unblurs div with id="background". Your `blur()` blurs an unknown element with id="map". See my working code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention is to blur the background whenever the input is empty. Here's some minimal code that accomplishes that:

```js
const bgDiv = document.getElementById("background");

// blur background image when input is empty
function blurOnEmptyInput() {
  var x = document.forms["search"]["searchInput"].value;
  if (x === "") {
    bgDiv.classList.add('blur');
  } else {
    bgDiv.classList.remove('blur');
  }
}
```

```css
/* style with CSS instead of embedding in JavaScript function */
.bg-image {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/300/100");
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(2px);
}

div {
  margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form name="search">
    <input placeholder="Search.." name="searchInput"
      onkeyup="blurOnEmptyInput();">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="background" class="bg-image blur"></div>
```